# Print text that appears after a substring match using awk in Perl

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a multiple strings, as shown below, in a file `MyFile`-

`1234|5|678|ABC|d|e| MyString - values: foo 1, bar 10%, baz 2/2, qux quux 10 sec, quuz 10km`

How to print the substrings `1234 10 sec` based on a sub-string match `qux quux`.

This is what i have tried - `grep -a "qux quux" MyFile | cut -d '|' -f 1,7 | awk '{print $1, " ",$13," ",$14}' |sed -e 's/|//' | sed -e 's/,//' > $output`

But if the contents of the string change, the above command ends up copying wrong values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk alone, assuming you want to capture everything up to a following comma:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v r="qux quux " '
    match($0,r "[^,]*") {print $1, substr($0,RSTART+length(r),RLENGTH-length(r))}
  ' MyFile
1234 10 sec
```

GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -F'|' 'match($0,/qux quux ([^,]*)/,a) {print $1, a[1]}' MyFile
1234 10 sec
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lne 'print "$F[0] $1" if /qux quux ([^,]*)/' MyFile
1234 10 sec
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.